# When im copying file with fs.rdbuf() i lose some data

Tags: c++, file, fstream

```
fs.open(pathString, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate |std::ios::in |std::ios::out );
std::remove("Temp.iqbin");
        std::fstream ofs1("Temp.iqbin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out | std::ios::app | std::ios::in);
        fs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        //Store vector concatenation data in Temp file
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            ofs1 << fs.rdbuf();
            fs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        }
```

size of original file is 4688kb (4800000bytes)

size of created file on 1st cycle iteration is 4684kb (4 796 416 bytes)

size of created file after cycle was complete is 37 496kb (38 395 904 bytes)

when i was test it on 174byte file, he works good.

file mostly contain zeroes, but i need this zeroes too)

Comment: the problem was in breakpoint stops. when i start it without breakpoints it was worked fine

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in breakpoint stops. when i start it without breakpoints it was worked fine